# Get CSS background width and background height individually from an element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

If you want the X and Y `background-position` of an HTML element, the following jQuery code works:

```
$(element).css("background-position-x");
$(element).css("background-position-y");
```

Is there an equivalent for background width and height? The code below fails.

```
$(element).css("background-position-width");
$(element).css("background-position-height");
```

Background size is obviously complicated by `contain`, `cover`, and other keywords, but is there a way to fetch background width and height when the `background-size` property contains numeric values?

To clarify, this is about reading defined values from the `background-size` property as individual ones, not simply how to obtain the size of an image used as a background element.

Comment: Are you looking for this? - https://jsfiddle.net/x4u2ndha/58/